# Preview csv data when file can have data with newline or data without newline

Tags: regex, shell, ubuntu, awk, sed

User can upload two types of files data . Please find the sample data below

```
Sample 1:

Name    mobile  url message text
test11  1234567890  www.example.com  "Data Test New
Date:27/02/2020
Items: 1
Total: 3
Regards
ABC DATa
Ph:091 : 123456789"
test12  1234567891   www.example.com  hello

Sample2

test12  1234567891   www.example.com  hello
test13  1234567892   www.example.com  hi
test14  1234567893   www.example.com  hi
```

User file can have 2-3 millions of records . So I want to give preview option to the user where user can preview first 10 lines of their uploaded file. To get first 10 lines I am using below command

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' 'NR>10{exit} {gsub(/\r?\n/, "\\n", RT); ORS=RT} 1' test.csv
```

it works perfectly when files rows have double value but for sample 2 it is printing all the records from file.

Below command is working for sample 2 but not for sample 1

```
head -n10 test.csv | tr '^' ','
```

Excpected Output:

```
Sample1:

Name    mobile  url message text
test11  1234567890  www.example.com  "Data Test New\nDate:27/02/2020\nItems: 1\nTotal: 3\nRegards\nABC DATa\nPh:091 : 123456789"
test12  1234567891   www.example.com  hello

Sample 2:

test12  1234567891   www.example.com  hello
test13  1234567892   www.example.com  hi
test14  1234567893   www.example.com  hi
```

I need a command which will work in both cases

Comment: What's your field separator? Multiple spaces, tab or a comma? You spoke about CSV.

Comment: @yes my field seprator can be comma, pipe and tab. Because I will apply apply same command for txt file as well

Comment: @user13000875, Sorry but still its not clear about logic of your expected output, how you are getting it, kindly do mention logic of getting sample expected output more clearly in your question for better understanding of your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I jsut want to get first 10 rows of a file

Comment: @user13000875, could you please do let us know if lines starting from `test` needs to be in single line you need? and empty lines and sample1 and sample2 are NOT in expected output? Kindly confirm it once.

Comment: @Luuk it's not working

Comment: A `regex` tag was used by OP along with `awk`, `sed`  and there is a good reason because this solution requires heavy use of `regex` **as evident from question and all the answers**. Please don't remove this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS='("[^"]*")?\r?\n' 'NF {
   ORS = gensub(/\r?\n(.)/, "\\\\n\\1", "g", RT)
   ++n
   print
}
n == 10 {exit}' file
```

Or a single line:

```sh
awk -v RS='("[^"]*")?\r?\n' 'NF{ORS = gensub(/\r?\n(.)/, "\\\\n\\1", "g", RT);  ++n; print} n==2{exit}' file
```

Comment: Can you convert it into one line. Because When I am implementing it inside my script I am getting issues

Comment: Thanks it's working perfectly. Your command has one more advantage there is no dependency on delimiter

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
       FS="[\t,|]"            # field separators: tab, comma and pipe
       RS="\r{0,1}\n"         # input record separator
     }

     $NF~/^"/ && $NF~/[^"]$/{ # if last field starts with " but does not end with "
       m=$0                   # build new row in variable m
       while ($0~/[^"]$/){    # loop until current row does not end with "
         getline              # read next row
         m=m "\\n" $0         # append current row to variable m
         NR--                 # decrease the row counter
       }
       $0=m                   # copy new build row to current row
     }

     NR<=10{print}' file
```

As one line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\t,|]"; RS="\r{0,1}\n"} $NF~/^"/ && $NF~/[^"]$/ {m=$0; while ($0~/[^"]$/){getline; m=m "\\n" $0; NR--}; $0=m} NR<=10{print}' file
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, OFS, **RS**, ORS, **NR**, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Are you sure this works? For first same running with `NR<=2` it prints header row and first line of 2nd record which is `test11  1234567890  www.example.com  "Data Test New` instead of full `test11  1234567890  www.example.com  "Data Test New\nDate:27/02/2020\nItems: 1\nTotal: 3\nRegards\nABC DATa\nPh:091 : 123456789"`

Comment: @anubhava you are correct. But your answer is working in all scenarios.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*$/{
         :a;N;//ba;s/\n/\\n/g};x;s/^/x/;/x{10}/{x;q};x' file
```

The solution is in two halves:

- The first part joins consecutive lines which have unbalanced quotes
- The second part counts the lines printed.

The first part, appends lines until double quotes are balanced (or not if there are no quotes). The newlines are then replaced by `\\n`.

The second part uses the hold space to maintain a counter (in the solution 10) which when reached terminates the processing.

N.B. This will work one invocation per file. To process more than one file at a time use:

```
sed -nsE '/^([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*$/{:a;N;//ba;s/\n/\\n/g};p
            x;s/^/x/;/x{10}/{:b;n;bb};x' file1 file2 ... filen
```